# How to split string of mulitdimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have string here
`String str1 = "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}"`

and the result i expect is like this

```
{1,2,3}
{4,5,6}
{7,8,9}
```

what method i use in java language?
Thanks.

---

i tried with split method then put each array into an arraylist variable "data".
result :

```
1,2,3
,
4,5,6
,
7,8,9
```

and try to delete the data array that is empty and which only has a string value"," result :

```
1,2,3
,
4,5,6
,
7,8,9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)
        at io.jhdf.examples.test2.lambda$0(test2.java:26)   
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1672)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
        at io.jhdf.examples.test2.main(test2.java:26)
```

and this is my code :

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        String str1 = "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}";
        String[] arrOfStr1 = str1.split("[{}]");

        //System.out.println(arrOfStr[2].length());

        for (String a1 : arrOfStr1){
            data.add(a1);
            System.out.println(a1);
        }
        data.removeIf(n -> (n.charAt(0)) == ',');
```

Comment: `System.out.println(str1.substring(1, str.length() - 1).replace(',', '\n'));`

Comment: Do you expect 3 substrings or do you want to parse that string into an `int[][]` or something like this? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** because you have some empty strings in your **arrOfStr1** array. The *n.charAt(0)* expression is causing the exception because there is no characters in some of the strings. Use the debugger to see whats really in the **data** array before you try to remove the single commas.

Anyways, here is the fix, modify one line in your code:

```
 data.removeIf(n -> n.equals("") || ( n.charAt(0)) == ',');
```

And by the way you could also use Streams. The whole code could also look like that:

```
String str1 = "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}";

    List<String> data =  Arrays.stream(str1.split("[{}]"))
            .filter(n -> !n.equals("") && ( n.charAt(0)) != ',')
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it works. thanks. I didn't pay attention to the empty array which is in the first two lines of the result